# How can I insert new entry into jQuery table through a modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table of data that I want to add additional info onto through a modal. steps:

1. The modal sits above the table
2. you click the modal
3. enter info for the form in the modal
4. click submit and modal closes and data appears in table

Any help with the code below would be greatly appreciated!

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var exampleDatatable = $('#example').DataTable({
        responsive: {
            details: {
                type: 'column',
                target: 'tr'
            }
        },
        columnDefs: [ {
            className: 'control',
            orderable: false,
            targets:   1
        } ],
        order: [ 1, 'asc' ],
        bFilter: true,
        bLengthChange: true,
        pagingType: "simple",
        "paging": true,
        "searching": true,
        "language": {
            "info": " _START_ - _END_ of _TOTAL_ ",
            "sLengthMenu": "<span class='custom-select-title'>Rows per page:</span> <span class='custom-select'> _MENU_ </span>",
            "sSearch": "",
            "sSearchPlaceholder": "Search",
            "paginate": {
                "sNext": " ",
                "sPrevious": " "
            },
        },
        dom:
            "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
            "<'pmd-card-footer' <'pmd-datatable-pagination' l i p>>",
    });

    $('#enter').click(function(){
      $row = $('<tr/>');
          cellVal = $("input1").val();
          $row.append($("<td/>").text(cellVal));
      $('example').append($row);
    });

    /// Select value
    $('.custom-select-info').hide();

    $(".custom-select-action").html('<button class="btn btn-sm pmd-btn-fab pmd-btn-flat pmd-ripple-effect btn-primary" type="button"><i class="material-icons pmd-sm">delete</i></button><button class="btn btn-sm pmd-btn-fab pmd-btn-flat pmd-ripple-effect btn-primary" type="button"><i class="material-icons pmd-sm">more_vert</i></button>');

} );
```

HTML:

```
    <section class="row component-section">
        <!-- table card code and example -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="component-box">
                <!-- table card example -->
            <!-- responsive table example -->
            <div class="pmd-card pmd-z-depth pmd-card-custom-view">
            <div class="pmd-card-body modal-btn">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"> 
                        <h3><button data-target="#form-dialog" data-toggle="modal" class="btn pmd-ripple-effect btn-primary pmd-z-depth" type="button">Submit a new Code</button></h3>
                        <div tabindex="-1" class="modal fade" id="form-dialog" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header bordered">
                                        <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
                                        <h2 class="pmd-card-title-text">New Code</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <form class="form-horizontal">
                                            <div class="form-group pmd-textfield pmd-textfield-floating-label">
                                                <label for="first-name">Code</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="mat-input form-control" id="test1" value="">
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pmd-modal-action">
                                        <button data-dismiss="modal" value="submit" id="hello" class="btn pmd-ripple-effect btn-primary" type="submit" href="/referal-page.html">Create</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <table id="example" class="table pmd-table table-hover table-striped display responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>

                        <tr>
                            <th>First name</th>
                            <th>Last name</th>
                            <th>Position</th>
                            <th>Office</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Ashton</td>
                            <td>Cox</td>
                            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>66</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Garrett</td>
                            <td>Winters</td>
                            <td>Accountant</td>
                            <td>Tokyo</td>
                            <td>63</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Ashton</td>
                            <td>Cox</td>
                            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>66</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Cedric</td>
                            <td>Kelly</td>
                            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>22</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger</td>
                            <td>Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Garrett</td>
                            <td>Winters</td>
                            <td>Accountant</td>
                            <td>Tokyo</td>
                            <td>63</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Ashton</td>
                            <td>Cox</td>
                            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>66</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Cedric</td>
                            <td>Kelly</td>
                            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>22</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Cedric</td>
                            <td>Kelly</td>
                            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>22</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Ashton</td>
                            <td>Cox</td>
                            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>66</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Cedric</td>
                            <td>Kelly</td>
                            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>22</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Donna</td>
                            <td>Snider</td>
                            <td>Customer Support</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>27</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Donna</td>
                            <td>Snider</td>
                            <td>Customer Support</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>27</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div> <!-- responsive table example end -->

            </div>
        </div> <!-- table card code and example end -->
    </section> <!-- table card end -->
```

Comment: I cant see all the fields in your modal ? .. only code field ? in which column you need to add this field ?

Comment: Even I cant see `enter` button id in your HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added snippet below for your solution. I have for now added hardcoded data on click of button in Modal. You can actually get the data there from fields of modal.
Run below code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var exampleDatatable = $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: {
      details: {
        type: 'column',
        target: 'tr'
      }
    },
    columnDefs: [{
      className: 'control',
      orderable: false,
      targets: 1
    }],
    order: [1, 'asc'],
    bFilter: true,
    bLengthChange: true,
    pagingType: "simple",
    "paging": true,
    "searching": true,
    "language": {
      "info": " _START_ - _END_ of _TOTAL_ ",
      "sLengthMenu": "<span class='custom-select-title'>Rows per page:</span> <span class='custom-select'> _MENU_ </span>",
      "sSearch": "",
      "sSearchPlaceholder": "Search",
      "paginate": {
        "sNext": " ",
        "sPrevious": " "
      },
    },
    dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
      "<'pmd-card-footer' <'pmd-datatable-pagination' l i p>>",
  });

  $('#hello').click(function() {
      exampleDatatable.row.add( [
            'rahul', // get your values from Modal popup here
            'N',
            'PM',
            'Mumbai',
             '27'
        ] ).draw( false );
  });

  /// Select value
  $('.custom-select-info').hide();

  $(".custom-select-action").html('<button class="btn btn-sm pmd-btn-fab pmd-btn-flat pmd-ripple-effect btn-primary" type="button"><i class="material-icons pmd-sm">delete</i></button><button class="btn btn-sm pmd-btn-fab pmd-btn-flat pmd-ripple-effect btn-primary" type="button"><i class="material-icons pmd-sm">more_vert</i></button>');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<section class="row component-section">
  <!-- table card code and example -->
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="component-box">
      <!-- table card example -->
      <!-- responsive table example -->
      <div class="pmd-card pmd-z-depth pmd-card-custom-view">
        <div class="pmd-card-body modal-btn">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
              <h3><button data-target="#form-dialog" data-toggle="modal" class="btn pmd-ripple-effect btn-primary pmd-z-depth" type="button">Submit a new Code</button></h3>
              <div tabindex="-1" class="modal fade" id="form-dialog" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header bordered">
                      <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
                      <h2 class="pmd-card-title-text">New Code</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <form class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group pmd-textfield pmd-textfield-floating-label">
                          <label for="first-name">Code</label>
                          <input type="text" class="mat-input form-control" id="test1" value="">
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pmd-modal-action">
                      <button data-dismiss="modal" value="submit" id="hello" class="btn pmd-ripple-effect btn-primary" type="submit" href="/referal-page.html">Create</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <table id="example" class="table pmd-table table-hover table-striped display responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>

            <tr>
              <th>First name</th>
              <th>Last name</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Office</th>
              <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Ashton</td>
              <td>Cox</td>
              <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
              <td>San Francisco</td>
              <td>66</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Garrett</td>
              <td>Winters</td>
              <td>Accountant</td>
              <td>Tokyo</td>
              <td>63</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Ashton</td>
              <td>Cox</td>
              <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
              <td>San Francisco</td>
              <td>66</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Cedric</td>
              <td>Kelly</td>
              <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
              <td>Edinburgh</td>
              <td>22</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Tiger</td>
              <td>Nixon</td>
              <td>System Architect</td>
              <td>Edinburgh</td>
              <td>61</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Garrett</td>
              <td>Winters</td>
              <td>Accountant</td>
              <td>Tokyo</td>
              <td>63</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Ashton</td>
              <td>Cox</td>
              <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
              <td>San Francisco</td>
              <td>66</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Cedric</td>
              <td>Kelly</td>
              <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
              <td>Edinburgh</td>
              <td>22</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Cedric</td>
              <td>Kelly</td>
              <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
              <td>Edinburgh</td>
              <td>22</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Ashton</td>
              <td>Cox</td>
              <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
              <td>San Francisco</td>
              <td>66</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Cedric</td>
              <td>Kelly</td>
              <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
              <td>Edinburgh</td>
              <td>22</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Donna</td>
              <td>Snider</td>
              <td>Customer Support</td>
              <td>New York</td>
              <td>27</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Donna</td>
              <td>Snider</td>
              <td>Customer Support</td>
              <td>New York</td>
              <td>27</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <!-- responsive table example end -->

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- table card code and example end -->
</section>
<!-- table card end -->
```

Comment: thank you! is there a way to enter the value at the top of the table?

Comment: **Position of newly added data in entirely based on the ordering condition applied to the DataTable.**

You need to **Draw DataTable with specified order** to achieve this